# How to trigger a pusher event using Laravel 5.3's Notification?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, pusher

iv'e been wondering where should i my code to trigger pusher events on client side using laravel notication?

iv'e been looking into laravel notification package inside my vendor folder, and there, i see `ChannelManager->sendNow` method that fires an event. i was wondering if i could just edit that or if i could override the `sendNow` method to trigger my custom pusher event

i tried firing an event inside the `toArray` method of my notification class but i dont know if this is the right way.

thanks